# Webpack 5 shared chunk file name

Tags: webpack-5

(Apologies if this has been asked and answered previously - I tried to search for a solution but was not able to find anything).

I'm upgrading an app from webpack 4 → 5.

The app has two entrypoints: "app" and "admin".

The goal is to reproduce the same outputs that webpack 4 did, specifically:

```sh
/dist/admin.js      // admin chunk
/dist/admin~app.js  // shared chunk for app + admin
/dist/app.js        // app chunk
/dist/runtime.js    // webpack runtime chunk (from runtimeChunk: "single")
/dist/vendor.js     // vendor chunk (node_modules)
```

The webpack 4 the config was:

```js
entry: {
  app: "app",
  admin: "admin"
},
output: {
  filename: "[name].js"
},
optimization: {
  moduleIds: "hashed",
  splitChunks: {
    chunks: "all",
    cacheGroups: {
      vendor: {
        name: "vendor",
        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/
      }
    }
  },
  runtimeChunk: "single"
}
```

This produces the expected output.

In webpack 5, we can now remove `output.filename` and `optimization.moduleIds` since those are the defaults, but everything else largely remains the same:

```js
entry: {
  app: "app",
  admin: "admin"
},
optimization: {
  splitChunks: {
    chunks: "all",
    cacheGroups: {
      vendor: {
        name: "vendor",
        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/
      }
    }
  },
  runtimeChunk: "single"
}
```

However, this produces the following output:

```
/dist/121.js        // shared chunk for app + admin
/dist/admin.js      // admin chunk
/dist/app.js        // app chunk
/dist/runtime.js    // runtime chunk
/dist/vendor.js     // vendor chunk
```

Note that the shared chunk that was previously named `admin~app.js` now has (what appears to be) a hashed module id as the name (`121.js`).

I am guessing that the difference is perhaps related to this change in the docs:

- In [webpack 4](https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputfilename), the `[name]` placeholder is described as "The module name"
- In [webpack 5](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#template-strings), the `[name]` placeholder is described as "The name of the chunk, if set, **otherwise the ID of the chunk**"

I know it's pedantic and it shouldn't really matter whether the file is called `admin~app` or `121` but is there a way that I can have the shared chunk named as it was in webpack 4?

Comment: Have you found solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I use a version of the code in this example in the docs: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunksname

This might work for you but I actually don't split out the node modules and just have a single cache group that includes vendor and non-vendor chunks but I use the same special `name` function.  I have no idea how or why it works but it seems to do what I mostly want.

```js
{
    //...
    optimization: {
        // Factor the webpack runtime out into a single dependency rather than
        // baking it into each entry point.
        // Include it before the other deps for each entry point.
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: function (module, chunks, cacheGroupKey) {
                        const moduleFileName = module
                            .identifier()
                            .split('/')
                            .reduceRight((item) => item);
                        // This is taken from the documentation but there
                        // seems to be no great explaination but it seems
                        // to be what we need, joining the entry point names
                        // together by ~.  We can then determine which chunk/file
                        // needs to be loaded by each entry point.
                        const allChunksNames = chunks.map((item) => item.name).join('~');
                        return `${cacheGroupKey}-${allChunksNames}-${moduleFileName}`;
                    },
                    chunks: 'all',
                    priority: -10,
                    reuseExistingChunk: true
                },
                commons: {
                    priority: -20,
                    reuseExistingChunk: true,
                    name: function (module, chunks, cacheGroupKey) {
                        const moduleFileName = module
                            .identifier()
                            .split('/')
                            .reduceRight((item) => item);
                        // This is taken from the documentation but there
                        // seems to be no great explaination but it seems
                        // to be what we need, joining the entry point names
                        // together by ~.  We can then determine which chunk/file
                        // needs to be loaded by each entry point.
                        const allChunksNames = chunks.map((item) => item.name).join('~');
                        return `${cacheGroupKey}-${allChunksNames}-${moduleFileName}`;
                    },
                    // Automatically split all code as needed into separate files.
                    chunks: 'all'
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My config looks more like this:

```js
{
    //...
    optimization: {
        // Factor the webpack runtime out into a single dependency rather than
        // baking it into each entry point.
        // Include it before the other deps for each entry point.
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        splitChunks: {
                commons: {
                    name: function (module, chunks, cacheGroupKey) {
                        const moduleFileName = module
                            .identifier()
                            .split('/')
                            .reduceRight((item) => item);
                        // This is taken from the documentation but there
                        // seems to be no great explaination but it seems
                        // to be what we need, joining the entry point names
                        // together by ~.  We can then determine which chunk/file
                        // needs to be loaded by each entry point.
                        const allChunksNames = chunks.map((item) => item.name).join('~');
                        return `${cacheGroupKey}-${allChunksNames}-${moduleFileName}`;
                    },
                    // Automatically split all code as needed into separate files.
                    chunks: 'all'
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ian - I had seen that example in the docs; but as per your "...seems to be no great explanation..." code comment, what is confusing to me is why there remains the `splitChunks.automaticNameDelimiter` config option (default: '~'), given that naming convention in webpack5 no longer seems to use this delimiter?  Perhaps this option is now deprecated, and the docs haven't been updated.

Comment: I don't want to complain too much because clearly a TON of work has been put into webpack.  Yet it seems that the "join the entry points" feature is now missing, for me it is more complicated because I try to conditionally include those deps on each page based on the entrypoint utilized.  So I have to parse the list of outputted files and build up a dep list for each entrypoint.

Comment: @Scott There is even more seemingly undocumented complexity with css files.  I'm 100% OK with just leaving this open and hoping someone that understands webpack comes along and puts in a more complete answer, even if its verbatim but with more docs. I just wanted to help you get something working.  I want a better answer too.

Comment: Thanks Ian.  FWIW - I've posted a question in the official webpack discussions as well, hoping that someone closer to the project can provide some answers: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/discussions/14451